# Comment status shows 'closed' in db, but it shows 'open' when i echo it

Tags: theme-development, comments

Here is database ss. And comment_status is `closed`

[image]

But when i print it, it shows `open`

```
echo $post->comment_status;
```

Also, in page settings, comments checkbox is unchecked.

[image]

So, i can't hide comments in pages. How can i fix it?

Comment: Are you sure, that you're printing comment_status for the same post? Maybe there is a custom wp_query that is modifying the global `$post` variable?

Comment: Yes you are right. I put another query in this page template and $post not see page ID. It gets $post from first post of custom query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing I would do to debug such case is printing `$post->ID` just before printing the comment status. (And make sure if it is equal to 414 - the post you’re checking in DB)

I’m almost certain that somewhere in your page you make another wp_query and modify the global `$post` variable. So when you’re printing the comment status it’s showing the real value but for different post.

If you do such wp_query, then you'll have to remember to use `wp_reset_postdata` after that loop, so the global `$post` variable is restored to its original value.

Comment: Yes. I make custom wp_query inside main page query. And `$post->ID` shows first post id from custom query. Can you advice me for fixing this?

Comment: I've updated my answer.